# Angular loop through Object in array

Tags: html, angular, typescript, loops

Hi this is my angular project and I want to get userName of user for every posted comment. The entities are from my spring boot project. Is there a way to get a username for every comment?

This is comment log.

[image]

This is my comments Service class

```
  getAllCommentsForPost(postId: string): Observable<Comment[]>{
    return this.http.get<Comment[]>(this.PATH_OF_API + "/api/comment/get"+postId)
 }
```

This is my component

```
   comments!: Comment[];
  constructor(private router: Router,private postService: PostService, private commentService: CommentService) { }

this.commentService.getAllCommentsForPost(this.router.url).subscribe((data: Comment[]) =>{
      this.comments = data;
    })
```

Html

```
 <div class="mb-1" style="width: 60%" *ngFor="let comment of comments">

    {{comment.comment}}
    <p *ngIf="comment.voteCount > 0" class="likes" style="color: green">  Likes: {{comment.voteCount}} </p>
    <p *ngIf="comment.voteCount == 0" class="like" style="color: black"> Likes: {{comment.voteCount}} </p>
    <p *ngIf="comment.voteCount < 0" class="likes" style="color: red"> Likes: {{comment.voteCount}} </p>
    <a [routerLink]="['/like', comment.commentId]">  <p>like</p>  </a>
  </div>
```

I am getting error when i add

```
{{comment.user.userName}} 
{{comment.user['userName']}}
```

this is my comment and user class

```
export class Comment {
  commentId!: number;
  comment!: string;
  voteCount!: number;
  dateCreated!: string;
  user!: string;
  postId!: number;
}


export class User {
  userName!: string;
  userPic!: string;
  gender!: string;

}
```

Comment: Can you share the error that you're seeing?

Comment: when i use {{comment.user.userName}} i get src/app/postinfo/postinfo.component.html:36:20 - error TS2339: Property 'userName' does not exist on type 'string[]'.

36     {{comment.user.userName}}

Comment: src/app/postinfo/postinfo.component.html:36:20 - error TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

36     {{comment.user['userName']}}

Comment: Can you share the Comment interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing should work. I would prevent such errors with the use of `?` when accessing props. It might be, that not each comment has a `userName` (perhaps a anonymous comment of a sort?).

Checks if object has properties to be accessed and if it does, contents of `*ngIf` is rendered in html.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="comment?.user?.userName"> 
  {{comment.user.userName}} 
</ng-container>
```

Afterwards implement `class Comment` fully. Paste your response JSON here to have it generate all the classes/interfaces for you. https://quicktype.io/typescript

Class `Commnet` prop `user` should be of type `User`. Also I would ditch the `!` unless you are sure what you are doing and you want acknowledge that the property will always be there to be accessed (I would doubt this) but then again, I don't know your API.

Place `User` inside of `Comment`, go over other types like this as well. If you resolve this, then the previous check for conditional property checks using `?` might become obsolete.

```js
export class Comment {
  commentId!: number;
  comment!: string;
  voteCount!: number;
  dateCreated!: string;
  user!: User;
  postId!: number;
}


export class User {
  userName!: string;
  userPic!: string;
  gender!: string;
}
```

Comment: I added this     {{comment?.user?.userName}} to my code and still get the error  TS2339: Property 'userName' does not exist on type 'string[]'.

34     {{comment?.user?.userName}}

Comment: It's hard to understand your conext how you are using this. But I am guessing in template literal. Add check the existence with `*ngIf` and then access when present. I have updated my code.

Comment: @Joosep.P check the `Comment` class... OP has defined `user` to be a string, whereas it is an object... should create a class for the user as well....

Comment: @AT82 ah yes... he has edited the question now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using latest version of Typescript
in new version of typescript there are **Optional Chaining** where your object are null & undefined then this **Optional Chaining** operator will help you determine this object id null or undefined
and in your case **Optional Chaining(?)** operator will help you
[Click here to known more about optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html)